# Using an interface for a class in Java

Tags: java

I'm a little bit confused about using an interface in Java.
I have created an interface for a Bag java class. It appears that the only way I can implement the interface is to declare explicitly in the Bag class header that the class is abstract. If I do this, then I will not be able to create another class, let us say a PiggyBank java class that would utilize the bag class. So this has led me to some confusion as to how I should go about it. Would it be possible to define a class, PiggyBank that extends the Bag class? I haven't finished the current Bag class as of yet because I'm not sure how to define some of the methods. Then I realized that since the class is now abstract, i'm not going to be able create a new instance of the class from a test class.

```
package bagimplementation;
/**
 An interface that the describes the operations of a bag of objects.
 @author Jeff nicholas
 * @param <T> The type of item being bagged
 */
public interface BagInterface <T> {
    /**Gets the current number of entries in this bag.
       @return the integer number of entries currently in the bag*/
    int getCurrentSize();

    /**Sees whether this bag is full.
       @return true if the bag is full, or false if not */
    boolean isFull();

    /**Sees whether this bag is empty.
       @return true if the bag is empty, or false if not */
    boolean isEmpty();

    /**Adds a new entry to this bag.
       @param newEntry the object to be added as a new entry.
       @return true if the addition is successful, or false if not */
    boolean add(T newEntry);

    /**Removes one unspecified entry from this bag, if possible.
       @return either the removed entry, if the removal was successful, or null*/
    T remove();

    /**Removes one occurrence of a given entry from this bag, if possible
       @param anEntry the entry the be removed.
       @return true if the removal was successful, or false if not */
    boolean remove(T anEntry);

    /**Removes all entries from this bag. */
    void clear();

    /**Counts the number of times a given entry appears in this bag.
       @param anEntry the entry to be counted.
       @return the number of times anEntry appears in the bag */
    int getFrequencyOf(T anEntry);

    /**Tests whether this bag contains a given entry.
     * @param anEntry the entry to locate
     * @return true if the bag contains anEntry, or false otherwise */
    boolean contaions(T anEntry);

    /**Creates an array of all entries that are in this bag.
     * @return a newly allocated array of all the entries in the bag*/
    T[] toArray();
}//end BagInterface

/**Bag class is not finished at this time */
package bagimplementation;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public abstract class Bag implements BagInterface<Bag>{

    private int size;
    private boolean full;
    private boolean empty;
    private int currentSize;

    public void setSize(int aSize){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a size for the bag.....");
        aSize = keyboard.nextInt();
        size = aSize;
    }//end setSize


    public int getCurrentSize(){
    return currentSize;
    }   


}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. If you create a concrete class that implements an interface, then you have to implement all of the methods which the interface provides. If you omit at least one method then the class has to be abstract.

Comment: I do this by declaring the class abstract? If I try to implement the class without declaring it so I am getting an error from netBeans IDE

Comment: I see that you are coming from the C++ world. There is no separation of declaration and definition of a class in Java. The definition and declaration have to be done in the same code piece.

Comment: If you can't implement the interface methods because you don't yet know how, just make them all say `throw new RuntimeException("Not yet implemented");` or something like that.  That's what I do.

Comment: Have a look at this article, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11155/Abstract-Class-versus-Interface. It will explain abstract classes and interfaces a little more for you.

Comment: By the way, making a class `abstract` is not really a solution.  A concrete class must implement all interface methods; an abstract class doesn't need to.  But whether the class is concrete or abstract must depend on your design.  Sometimes, compiler error messages or IDE messages seem to imply that you can make a class abstract to get it to compile.  But that's the tail wagging the dog, in my opinion.

Comment: @ajb Wouldn't it be better to use [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html)?

Comment: @Jagger Probably, since it's also an unchecked exception.  However, since the point was just to come up with **any** code that will get the class to compile until I can think of how to implement the bodies, it probably doesn't matter all that much.  The default used by Eclipse is either an empty body or `return`'ing a dummy value, which I don't like because it's more accident-prone (you can forget to put in the real body and the program could still appear to work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must implement all of the methods from the interface unless you declare the class as abstract. If you don't know how to implement some methods, just add some temporary stub implementations like this and then when you figure it out, replace it with real implementation:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    // TODO: implement functionality
    return false;
}
```

Some IDEs also generate these stub methods for you when you choose to implement an interface.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that if I add all those methods from the interface to the body of the Bag class I don't have to declare the Bag class abstract in the class header?

Comment: There is no separation of declaration and definition in Java like it is for example in C++.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, an interface is a set of methods that a class is expected to implement. A class that declares `implements BagInterface` must provide implementations of all the methods declared in the interface.

The exception to that is if the class is declared `abstract`. In that case any concrete class that extends the abstract class must implement the missing methods. A class with missing methods cannot be instantiated, because it has missing functionality.

If you want a `Bag` base class that doesn't implement all the methods in your interface, you can define it as an abstract class. But you won't be able to instantiate it directly (because it is missing some methods that your interface specifies must be implemented). To instantiate, you would need a concrete (i.e. not abstract) subclass that implemented all the missing methods.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are coming from the C++ world. In C++ first you declare a class and its methods for example in a header file `.h` and then implementations in a `.cpp` file.

In Java you declare and define methods in the same place (file). For example: `(misc/Bag.java)`.

```
package misc;

public class Bag {
   public void a() {
      System.out.println("a");
   }

   public void b() {
      System.out.println("b");
   }
}
```

You can separate the definition from the implementation by using an interface. An interface is equal to a C++ class which declares all of the methods as purely virtual.

misc/Baggable.java

```
package misc;

public interface Baggable {
    void a();
    void b();
}
```

misc/Bag.java

```
package misc;

public class Bag implements Baggable {
    public void a() {
      System.out.println("a");
    }

    public void b() {
      System.out.println("b");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick example of abstract methods and classes

When the `abstract` modifier is used in java and of course many other programming languages it refers to that class, method etc being only partially implemented.

The reason for doing this is actually quite simple, lets say for example we have an abstract baseclass called Animals, and a subclass of the Animals class called Dolphin.

If we have multiple different types of animal which share common attributes i.e. they all have a type, weight, name etc then it makes sense to reduce the amount of code which must be rewritten in order to achieve the same functionality for each class.

Abstract methods provide the ability to ensure that all necessary methods are always included in inherited subclasses. You still have the freedom to include local methods in your derived subclass to ensure that the class reflects its original purpose i.e. add more detail to it to ensure it differs from other derived subclasses.

**Animals Class**

```
public abstract class Animals
{
  //Methods are only partially complete as they will be completed in subclasses
  public abstract void setAnimalType( AnimalType type );
  public abstract Type getAnimalType();
}
```

**Dolphin Class ( inherits abstract methods from Animals class)**

```
    public class Dolphin extends Animals
    {
      AnimalType animalType = new AnimalType();

      //All abstract methods found in Animals class MUST be implemented in its child class Dolphin
      public void setAnimalType( AnimalType type )
      {
         //Notice that now we have to implement the rest of the method that has been inherited from Animals baseclass
         animalType = type;
      }

      public Type getAnimalType()
      {
        return animalType;
      }
}
```